# Access CouchDB with external URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, couchdb

I have installed CouchDB in my AWS server. When I run the command

```
curl localhost:5984
```

then I got a response like:

> {"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"b7a38141c61a37390945a99fd88f0015","version":"1.6.0","vendor":{"version":"15.10","name":"Ubuntu"}}

But when I run this command:

```
curl ip_address:5984
```

then it gives:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to Ip-address port 5984: Connection refused

Comment: Did you open port `5984` in your security group?

Comment: Yes, I added the inbound rule for TCP 5984 port in the security group.

Comment: Is `CouchDB` listening for connections from outside the host? What is the output of `netstat -plan | grep 5984`?

Comment: When I run "netstat -plan | grep 5984" I got response                               
  (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5984          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CouchDB` is not listening on all interfaces. Edit your `couch.ini` file and modify the line to:

```
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

and restart couch service. If it still doesn't work, post the output of `netstat -plan | grep 5984`.

Clearly explained here: [CouchDB HTTP Server](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/http.html)

**bind_address** : Defines the IP address by which CouchDB will be accessible:

```
[httpd]
bind_address = 127.0.0.1
```

To let CouchDB listen any available IP address, just set up 0.0.0.0 value:

```
[httpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. the above steps work for me.